# what's wrong in this statement? I am using React.js

Tags: javascript, react

It is showing an error over here in this line. I don't know what's wrong here.

```
<div className={StyleSheet.home}>
```

Comment: Can you paste the stylesheet import line used in your JS?

Comment: import Style from './NavBar.module.css';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this to styles

```
import styles from './NavBar.module.css';
```

and this to styes.home

```
<div className={styles.home}>
```

that should fix your error